# Can't find x11 terminal in gnuplot Octave on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, gnuplot, octave, x11

I am running Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.4.

Installed Octave 3.8.1 via Homebrew which came with gnuplot 4.6

Have XQuartz 2.7.6 installed.

I restarted my computer after all was done.

In order to plot in **octave-cli** everyone states that I should just 'set terminal x11' BUT I don't even have x11 listed when I run 'set terminal' in **gnuplot**

Of course octave-cli will complain that my terminal is unknown.

```
octave:1> x=1;

octave:2> plot(x);

gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6" dashlength 1

                      ^

         line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

What did I do wrong? How can I debug this situation?

```
rami@ramis-macbook:~> gnuplot 

G N U P L O T

Version 4.6 patchlevel 5    last modified February 2014

Build System: Darwin x86_64

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2014

Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info

faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"

immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')



Terminal type set to 'unknown'

gnuplot> set terminal



Available terminal types:

           canvas  HTML Canvas object

              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile

          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)

            corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW

             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text

              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)

            eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment

              emf  Enhanced Metafile format

            emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials

         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package

              fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor

              gif  GIF images using libgd and TrueType fonts

             gpic  GPIC -- Produce graphs in groff using the gpic preprocessor

          hp2623A  HP2623A and maybe others

           hp2648  HP2648 and HP2647

             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]

           imagen  Imagen laser printer

             jpeg  JPEG images using libgd and TrueType fonts

            latex  LaTeX picture environment

              lua  Lua generic terminal driver

               mf  Metafont plotting standard

              mif  Frame maker MIF 3.00 format

               mp  MetaPost plotting standard

             pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)

              png  PNG images using libgd and TrueType fonts

       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)

          pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials

            pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials

         pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros

              qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)

            regis  REGIS graphics language

              svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics driver

          tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators

          tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals

          texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment

             tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]

             tikz  TeX TikZ graphics macros via the lua script driver

         tkcanvas  Tk/Tcl canvas widget [perltk] [interactive]

             tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials

          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device

Press return for more:   

            vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator

            xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/cant-plot-with-gnuplot-on-my-mac). Basically `gnuplot` needs to be reinstalled as:

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-x11
```

[This page](http://jatinganhotra.com/blog/2014/01/21/installing-octave-on-os-x-10-dot-9-mavericks/) also helps with troubleshooting Octave installation on Mavericks.

Comment: It's not working on el-capitan. I keep on getting SHA256 mismatch error. And yes, I have updated and upgraded brew. Suggestions?

Comment: Turns out, Sourceforge was acting up :|

Comment: Awesome, thanks. just a small update: brew uninstall gnuplot --ignore-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

On El Capitan it shows error. So here's what you do:

1. Install Xquartz first...
2. `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt`
3. Open 'Xquartz' from Applications and NOT the 'Terminal'.
4. `gnuplot`
5. gnuplot > `set terminal xterm 6. plot sin(x)

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three options:

1. `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-x11`
2. `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt`
3. `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt5`

The graphical quality of plots is much better with option 3 compared to option 1.