# WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal. No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'

Tags: macos, gnuplot

i am following the great machine learning course given by Andrew Wu from Stanford. When I executed plot function in ex5 file, the octave cli command line reports the following warning:

```
set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6" dashlength 1
                      ^
         line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
```

The calculation works but all the graphs were not drew by plot. 
I tried set terminal qt or others like x11, but none of them worked.
The solution in this post [Can't find x11 terminal in gnuplot Octave on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721305/cant-find-x11-terminal-in-gnuplot-octave-on-mac-os) does not work either.

my mac is Yosemite 10.10.3 
my gnuplot is

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 
...
Terminal type set to 'unknown'
```

my XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2)

Anyone knows how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: You have a gnuplot binary that lacks the necessary aqua terminal for mac. Wherefrom have got it?

Answer (score 12):

Try reinstalling `gnuplot` `--with-qt`, e.g.

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt
```

Comment: This worked for me, while setting up `terminal` was not enough. In my case I also add to install manually `jpegsrc` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703296/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libjpeg-8-dylib-homebrew-php

Comment: this is what i needed to do on Mojave. I probably had an earlier version of gnuplot installed and when  I ran `brew install gnuplot --with-qt` it didn't override.

Comment: This command didn't work for me. I was able to make it work with following changes `brew uninstall gnuplot` and then `brew install Caskroom/cask/aquaterm`. Then `brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt4`.

Answer (score 10):

1) Open up terminal and try running

```
gnuplot
```

2) In gnuplot, run the command

```
set terminal
```

This should list all your available terminal types.

3) In octave, pick an available gnuplot terminal type and run setenv(). For example this could be

```
setenv('GNUTERM','qt')
setenv('GNUTERM','x11')
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue last night. The simplest solution I could find was to set terminal to `qt` from Octave.

```
setenv('GNUTERM','qt')
```

Now you can call `plot` as usual.

Comment: I tried this solution before and did not work. Then I restart my computer and now your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me!  reinstalling gnuplot didn't help but this did thanks!

Comment: @Akshay Thank you for this, all suggestions above didn't work for me except this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: sudo apt install gnuplot-qt. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me, what fixed it was:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/aquaterm
brew upgrade gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt4
```