# gnuplot can't plot,how to fix it?

Tags: lua, gnuplot

I try to use Octave to plot data but failed. I can't find x11 or something in the list. Why do people say set environment to x11? How to fix it?
I try to use Octave to plot data but failed. I can't find x11 or something in the list. Why do people say set environment to x11? How to fix it?
I try to use Octave to plot data but failed. I can't find x11 or something in the list. Why do people say set environment to x11? How to fix it?

BlueCat56:Homebrew Mac$ gnuplot

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'unknown'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
gnuplot> set terminal

Available terminal types:
       canvas  HTML Canvas object
          cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
      context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
        corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
         dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
          dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
        eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
          emf  Enhanced Metafile format
        emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
     epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
          fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
          gif  GIF images using libgd and TrueType fonts
         hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
         jpeg  JPEG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
        latex  LaTeX picture environment
          lua  Lua generic terminal driver
           mf  Metafont plotting standard
           mp  MetaPost plotting standard
         pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
          png  PNG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
   postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
     pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
        pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
     pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
          qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)
          svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics
      tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
      tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
      texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
         tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]
         tikz  TeX TikZ graphics macros via the lua script driver
     tkcanvas  Tk/Tcl canvas widget [perltk] [interactive]
         tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials
      unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
        vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
        xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

gnuplot>

Comment: Have you tried any of the other terminal types to see if they do what you want? What sort of plotted output do you want from this command? What format do you want it in? Where do you want to have/save/see it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find x11 terminal in gnuplot Octave on Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721305/cant-find-x11-terminal-in-gnuplot-octave-on-mac-os)